# Failed connect two tasks in ECS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, nestjs, grpc, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

context:

- I have 2 microservices service A and service B
- service A is a general `nestjs` microservice while service B is using `nestjs` + `gRPC`
- service A calls service B API

local test:

- local: service A and B are brought up using separate docker-compose.yml and I set them explicitly to use the same network. Everything works as expected.

PROBLEM:
I deployed both services to AWS ECS Fargate. Each of them has an individual task definition. I setup service discovery for service B (A type) and the Service discovery endpoint is `serviceb.local`. Currently connection between service A and service B are not working. I keep receiving `ERROR 14 connection not established` error.

QUESTION:
How do i make containers in two different tasks talk to one another.

Code:

- register Service B's client in Service A

```
@Global()
@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: SERVICE_B_NAME,
        transport: Transport.GRPC,
        options: {
          url: 'serviceb.local',
          package: SERVICE_B_PACKAGE_NAME,
          protoPath: 'node_modules/services-proto/proto/serviceb.proto',
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
```

- bootstrap Service B

```
  const app: INestMicroservice = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.GRPC,
    options: {
      url: '0.0.0.0:50051',
      package: protobufPackage,
      protoPath: join('node_modules/services-proto/proto/serviceb.proto'),
    },
  });
```

What I have tries:

- I called service B's public IP from local postman and everything works;
- I used Cloud9 IDE and verified that Service discovery endpoint `serviceb.local` is successfully resolved to the public IP;
- Locally testing in docker works as expected;

Comment: Sounds like it's probably a security group issue. Are they both in the same VPC? What are the security group settings for service B?

Comment: @MarkB Hey Mark, thanks for replying. Yep, both are in the same VPC. I have setup service B's security group inbound rule to allow tcp request on 50051 from anywhere. I also tried to enable all traffic from anywhere just to make sure the security group doesn't affect the connection

Comment: The closest implementation to your docker local is to create one service, one task definition with 2 containers inside, with a bridge network.

Comment: @HùngNguyễn yeah that could be an option but we are using different repos on github and using github actions for CD deployment. Scaling independently could be a concern as well. We don't want to deploy multiple services everytime when we just touched one and want to keep the scaling independently. Any suggestions?